# JavaFx ml Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx-2, fxml, scenebuilder

ive posted a questio before about this topic and ive gotten far but all of a sudden hit a wall

So the thing is ive grown tired of the build in gui builder for Eclipse and i want to try out JavaFx Scene builder so far ive installed e(fx)clipse and i have also installed the newest version of JDK

the guy from my previous question gave me this link: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/fxml_tutorial.htm

it basicly shows how i can start by creating FXML projects in java. However the guide for this is ment for Netbeans and when i try to follow the steps on creating the project i fail at the following thing:

2.In the JavaFX application category, choose JavaFX FXML Application. Click Next

i simply do not have an option to choose JavaFx FxML Application.

So my question is, do any of you guys have a guide for this for eclipse or does any of you guys have any experiance with this and are able to share what i am suppose to do when i want to build my gui in JavaFx Scene builder?

Hope one of you are able to help me

Best Regards

Marc Rasmussen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install [e(fx)](http://efxclipse.org/) plugin to your eclipse .

Comment: Ive already used the installation guide on that website but i am still not able to create an JavaFX FXML Application project!

Comment: hmm , if you installed that plugin , choose javaFX project then create a fxml file in that project (cause e(fx) don't create fxml file automatically)

Comment: How do i do that? can you like guide me step by step? i am really clueless :S

Comment: Like the real question is how do i import the GUI (that i created in JavaFx Scene builder) into my application and use it with the classes ive created?

Comment: in your JavaFX project , right click on package -> new - > other -> type fxml in filter ->select new FXML document .

Comment: if you created a GUI in scenebuilder then just copy that fxml file to your JavaFX project :)

Comment: So i do like this:

New project -> i go under JavaFx then choose ?? then name the project -> >and go under SRC then right click the package
new other type in FXML -> Select new FXML document and then what? :)

Comment: choose javaFX project . after created FXML right click on it choose open with scene builder .....

Comment: But i cannot choose JavaFx FxML Application i can only choose JavaFx Application (or something simallar) which opens like 3 - 4 packages

Comment: Anyone know what kind of project/class i should create when i want to get my Scene builder Gui into my current project

Comment: You just need to have .fxml file in your project. SceneBuilder works with plain fxml files, it doesn't require any project files.